# How do I set MySQL host to something othen than 'localhost'?

Tags: mysql, host

I know that the mysql host is automatically set to localhost. I want to change the host so it points at another db. Where is the host set? In some config file that I'm not aware of? Is it a command?

Comment: do you mean another db server?

Comment: In MySQL Workbench? PHP? C#? C++? What language/what software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql -u user -h remotehost remotedatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

Check also that your my.cnf isn't enabling skip-networking. bind-address can be used to make it listen on specific addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard % can be used to mean all hosts, if you're referring to GRANT statements.